# Sed: Append text containing new lines characters after the first line of a file

Tags: command-line, bash, sed

I am trying to programatically build a changelog by redirecting the output of `git shortlog` into a CHANGELOG.md file.

My changelog outputs this (abridged):

```
Brendan Deere (4):
      Fix dependency conflicts
```

My changelog File (empty) looks like this:

```
CHANGELOG
===
```

The command I am trying to use is: 
`sed  "2a $(git shortlog)" ./CHANGELOG.md`

But I get this error: `sed: -e expression #1, char 30: extra characters after command`

What I want is:

```
CHANGELOG
===
Brendan Deere (4):
      Fix dependency conflicts
```

Can someone help connect the dots i'm missing?

Comment: You are trying to put the output of `git shortlog` after the second line in the CHANGELOG?

Comment: Yes thats correct. I will be doing this at several points in the git history and I would like to (if possible) always insert after the 2nd line so that the change log is reverse chronological from top to bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something super basic like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
head -n 2 CHANGELOG.md >CHANGELOG.md.tmp
git shortlog >>CHANGELOG.md.tmp
tail -n +3 CHANGELOG.tmp >> CHANGELOG.md.tmp
rm CHANGELOG.md
mv CHANGELOG.md.tmp CHANGELOG.md
```

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty fair. The K.I.S.S. principle might be the way to go here.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to run your sed `sed  "2a $(git shortlog)" ./CHANGELOG.md` but I could't figure out a solution.
I would like to see a fix :).

If 'git shortlog' was a file, a sed solution would be with the `r` command to read the file.

`sed  2r shortlog' ./CHANGELOG.md`

A GNU sed solution could be that

`sed '2 {h;s/.*/git shortlog/e;H;g}' ./CHANGELOG.md`

Answer (score 1):

When the text to be appended/inserted is more than one line, every line *except* the last must end with backslash-newline instead of the normal newline:

```
sed "2a $(git shortlog | sed '$! s/$/\\/')" old >new
```

Alternatively, kind of a variation on [Paulo's](https://superuser.com/a/1260699/333316) 'gsed s/whatever/cmd/e', you could do:

```
awk '1;NR==2{system("git shortlog")}' old >new
# note: 1 is the simplest possible pattern that matches all lines;
# since no action is given the default is to print each line;
# after printing line 2 we run the command with output to same stdout
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't remember to put backslashes at the end of line.

Comment: `awk -i inplace '1;NR==2{system("git shortlog")}' CHANGELOG.md`

Answer (score 0):

> The command I am trying to use is: sed  "2a $(git shortlog)" ./CHANGELOG.md
>
> But I get this error: sed: -e expression #1, char 30: extra characters
> after command

You get this error because the command that's being actually run, due to the expansion by the shell, looks like

`sed '2a Brendan Deere (4)[...]'`

which is not a valid `sed` command as the newlines are not escaped.

To achieve what you want, you can do the following with GNU `sed`:

`gsed -i '2 {h;s/.*/git shortlog/e;H;g};3,$d' CHANGELOG.md`

It will:

1. Keep the 2 first lines of `CHANGELOG.md`
2. Append the output of `git shortlog`
3. Ignore anything beyond (and including) the 3rd line of `CHANGELOG.md`
4. Write everything back into `CHANGELOG.md` (creating a temporary
   file)

Note that you need to be certain that, at any call, including the first, `CHANGELOG.md` has 2 or more lines, otherwise this command will do nothing.